# How to apply a XSL template only on elements containing a child with a particular attribute value and element value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML (partial) document :

```
<export>
<table name="CLIENT">
    <row>
        <col name="CODE_CLIENT" type="System.String">1000010026</col>
       <col name="LIBELLE" type="System.String">Test|</col>
        <col name="PROSPECT" type="System.Decimal">1</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="CODE_CLIENT" type="System.String">1000010025</col>
        <col name="LIBELLE" type="System.String">Rue de la 2eme ad|</col>
        <col name="PROSPECT" type="System.Decimal">0</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="CODE_CLIENT" type="System.String">1000010125</col>
       <col name="LIBELLE" type="System.String">Test4</col>
        <col name="PROSPECT" type="System.Decimal">0</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="CODE_CLIENT" type="System.String">1000010035</col>
        <col name="LIBELLE" type="System.String">Rue</col>
        <col name="PROSPECT" type="System.Decimal">1</col>
    </row>
    </table></export>
```

and the following XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="export/table[@name='CLIENT']"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
        SOME TEMPLATE CODE

  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to apply the first template (match="/") only to the "rows" that have prospect value to 1. In my exemple that would only transform the first and last rows.

I tried

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="export/table[@name='CLIENT']/row[col[@name='PROSPECT']=1]"/>
```

but that gave me a syntax error.

Anyone knows how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.1" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="export/table[@name='CLIENT']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[col[@name='PROSPECT' and text() = '1']]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    SOME TEMPLATE CODE
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Though your try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  export/table[@name='CLIENT']/row[col[@name='PROSPECT']=1]
"/>
```

*should* work as well (it's not as obvious, but it is not wrong *per se*). Not sure why it does not work for you.

Comment: Tomalak, thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and I had the same error I had with my version : 
']' required, '@' found (translated from french)

:-(

Comment: Tomalak, I am sorry, I did not tried exactly your solution but directly : 
<xsl:apply-templates select="export/table[@name='CLIENT']/row[col[@name='PROSPECT' and text() = '1']]"/>

I'm going to try your solution as is right now.

Comment: By the way, please tell the XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: That worked ! !
Thank you Tomalak !
I'm using thx XSLT Processor of the .NET 3.5. 
By the way, do you guys have a way to test a XSL stylesheet ? Sort of XLST Tester ?

Comment: In terms of "debugging"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Careful: entriely untested. It might not even parse correctly.

```
<xsl:template match="row[string(./col[@name='PROSPECT']) = '1']">

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk. I did not try your anwser, as I started with Tomalak's one, but it seems pretty nice too. I keep the exemple for further use ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your apply-templates and it didn't fail. Are you sure error is in the apply-templates?

Comment: The error I got was : 
']' required, '@' found (translated from french)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="export/table[@name='CLIENT']/row/col[text()='1' and @name='PROSPECT']"/>
```